# removing the words after a specific sign in every sentence in a string

Tags: python, string, indexing, del

1. this is the string for example:
   'I have an apple. I want to eat it. But it is so sore.'
   and I want to convert it to this one:
   'I have an apple want to eat it is is so sore'

Comment: Please specify programming language you're using in tags

Comment: Why are there 2 'is' in the line after 'eat'? As I understand you want to remove the words after '.' right?

Comment: assuming `it is is` in your output is `it it is` and `s` is your string. `' '.join([y for y in [x for x in s.replace('. ', '. $').split()] if "$" not in y]).replace(".", "")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it without regexes, using `del` as you have mentioned:

```
def remove_after_sym(s, sym):
    # Find first word
    first = s.strip().split(' ')[0]

    # Split the string using the symbol
    l = []
    s = s.strip().split(sym)

    # Split words by space in each sentence
    for a in s:
        x = a.strip().split(' ')
        del x[0]
        l.append(x)

    # Join words in each sentence
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] = ' '.join(l[i])

    # Combine sentences
    final = first + ' ' + ' '.join(l)
    final = final.strip() + '.'

    return final
```

Here, sym is a `str` (a single character).

Also I have used the word 'sentence' very liberally as in your example, `sym` is a dot. But here sentence really means parts of the string broken by the symbol you want.

Here is what it outputs.

```
In [1]: remove_after_sym(string, '.')
Out[1]: 'I have an apple want to eat it it is so sore.'
```